# Show/Hide using toggle saving to cookie

Tags: jquery

Can this be improved to have only one toogle function?

```
var show = $("#shows ul li");   
show.addClass("active");

$(show).each(function(c){
    var cvalue = $.cookie('show' + c);
   if ( cvalue == 'closed' + c ) { 
        $(this).css({display:"none"});
        $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
   };
}); 

$("#shows li.active").toggle(function(){
    var num = show.index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    var cookieValue = 'closed' + num;
    $(this).slideUp(500);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { path: '/', expires: 10 }); 
},function(){
    var num = $(this).index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    $(this).slideDown(500);
    $(this).addClass("active");        
    $.cookie(cookieName, null, { path: '/', expires: 10 });
});

$("#shows li.inactive").toggle(function(){
    var num = show.index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    $(this).slideDown(500);
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');       
    $.cookie(cookieName, null, { path: '/', expires: 10 });
},function(){
    var num = show.index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    var cookieValue = 'closed' + num;
    $(this).slideUp(500);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { path: '/', expires: 10 }); 
});
```

Comment: This question would be better addressed at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
$("#shows li").toggle(function(){

    var isactive = $(this).hasClass("active") ? true : false;

    var num = show.index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    var cookieValue = null;

    if(isactive){
        cookieValue = 'closed' + num;
        $(this).slideUp(500);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
        $(this).slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');       
    }

    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { path: '/', expires: 10 }); 

},function(){
    var isactive = $(this).hasClass("active") ? true : false;

    var num = $(this).index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    var cookieValue = null;

    if(isactive){
        $(this).slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass("active");        
    }else{
        cookieValue = 'closed' + num;
        $(this).slideUp(500);
        $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    }
    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { path: '/', expires: 10 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup, you can definitely reduce those to a single, short `.toggle`. For example, using the `toggleClass` and `slideToggle` methods:

```
$("#shows li").toggle(function(){
    var num = show.index(this);
    $(this).slideToggle(500);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    var cookieValue = ($(this).hasClass("active") ? 'show' : 'closed') + num;
    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { path: '/', expires: 10 }); 
}
```

Do you really need both `.active` and `.inactive` classes? I would suggest the elements simply toggle between the `.active` class (and nothing, which implies 'inactive').

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will makes things look good:

```
function func1() {
    var num = show.index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    var cookieValue = 'closed' + num;
    $(this).slideUp(500);
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { path: '/', expires: 10 }); 
}

function func2() {
    var num = $(this).index(this);
    var cookieName = 'show' + num;
    $(this).slideDown(500);
    $(this).addClass("active");        
    $.cookie(cookieName, null, { path: '/', expires: 10 });
}

$("#shows li.active").toggle(func1,func2);
$("#shows li.inactive").toggle(func2,func1);
```